# Python script not running from terminal [after being added to PATH]

Tags: python, windows, cmd, environment-variables

I am trying to run a python script from CMD (let's say *sample.py*) and I have added the directory of *sample.py* to my PATH. When I run *"sample.py"* in CMD it opens the file in my editor meaning it recognizes it. However, when I run "python *sample.py*" (python.exe added to path) I get the error:

`python: can't open file 'sample.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory".`

Why does *sample.py* not run with `python` but opens otherwise? I am using a Windows machine.

Comment: Try going to that directory and run the file. Because I am not sure where and what path you have added.

Comment: You need to add a Windows tag.  In Linux/MacOS/etc, this is usually handled by adding a shebang to the top of the file, making the file executable, and setting `PATH` correctly.  For Windows, see [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/faq/windows.html#how-do-i-make-python-scripts-executable).

Comment: Adding to path means the OS can run Python without the full file path. It also means that the OS can open your .py without the full file path. But when you run "python [filename]" you're no longer asking the OS to open your file, you're asking Python to open it. Python needs to know where the file is. See Guidot's answer.

Comment: Try "python -m sample"

Answer (score 1):

Adding the directory of the Python file to run to PATH does not help, since it is only used by the operating system to resolve directly executable stuff.

In this case you need to specify the path as in

> python path/to/script/script.py

An alternative is to add a special first line into the Python file [as in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2429511/1435475) and make it directly executable (depending on OS used).

For details you may also want to refer to the corresponding [PEP-397](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0397/).

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. What would be a way to successfully execute "python sample.py" (without including the full path) in the windows terminal?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the full path *to your `python.exe` file* to the `PATH` environment variable, **not** your `sample.py` file.

Then your command

```
python sample.py
```

will launch your script file, supposing you enter that command from the directory containing the `sample.py` file.